# In C# when I write a query to update there occurs an error "Syntax Error in UPDATE query"

Tags: c#, sql

In C# when I write a query to update there is an error

> Syntax Error in UPDATE query

My code:

```
public void Update()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\Employees.mdb");
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE employee SET ([Name],[Jobtitle],[Company])Values ('" + Name + "','" + Jobtitle + "','" + Company + "') where [EmpID] = '" + EmpID + "'", conn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 4):

This is not the right syntax for UPDATE statements.
You should do this instead: `SET column_1 = 'value 1', column_2 = 'value 2'`

This is probably unrelated to your issue (unless there are special characters in the variables), but you should not use concatenation in SQL requests.

Use [prepared requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156242/539465) instead.

Comment: I would add that the connection should be closed as well after the command is executed

Comment: @MuftahAltrhoni: Another posssible issue is that `EmpID` might be numeric. If it is, then drop the single quotes around it. But using [command parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will solve the issue anyway.

Comment: @StevenWood I would argue he use a `using` statement. =)

Comment: @Yatrix Yes I would use a Using as well but the important thing is that the connection is closed in whatever manner, but fair point

Comment: i appreciate all your comments, i have solved it, thank a lot to evrybody